# Excel Formula Less Then 10%

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am in need of an equation that will highlight a cell red if it is equal to less then 10% of a different cell. Is this possible?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please provide a sample for us understand your issue better?

Maybe you could use Conditional Formatting.

[image]

I use formula `=B1<0.1*A1` to highligt data in Column B which is less then 10% of corresponding values in Column A.

If it is compared with a fixed cell, you can add the "$" absolute reference symbol, such as comparing the data in column B with 10% of the data in A2.

[image]